# Is there a way to make embedded Google Maps a static non clickable image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Unfortunately, on a site that I'm working on, the StreetView image of the business premises is out of date and not very flattering of the business.

Is there any way to make (via the Maps API) the map image a static image, which doesn't link to the full Google Maps page showing the StreetView image?

I'm trying to avoid manually embedding an image as I want to be able to do this programmatically.

Thank you.
Prembo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep,  take a look at the static maps api.  There is an example of exactly what you need.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Thank you @javram - exactly what I was after.

Comment: Static maps are good if they are high enough resolution for your purposes, but they do max out at 640 (1280 if you use scale=2, but that's the same size map with twice as many pixels).  If you need a larger map you'll need to use the non-static version, but by setting `disableDefaultUI: true`, `scrollable: false`, `draggable: false` you can get something very similar.

Answer (score 6):

I found a really simple solution to this, in my case I wanted an interactive map on desktop and a static map on mobile.

Using media queries I added the attribute `{pointer-events: none !important;}` to the parent div wrapping my map when changing to mobile.

Comment: thanks; I also set this in the map options since it's static: `disableDefaultUI: true,`

Comment: Disabling `draggable` in the map options achieves the same.  To make something similar to the static maps (which are too small for larger devices) you can use `disableDefaultUI: true`, `scrollable: false`, `draggable: false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could style the map so it can't scroll, zoom, street view... etc.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions